# How to collect left values from an array of TaskEithers when using fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I have a function that broadcasts an event to my subscribers and the outcome is a `TaskEither<Error, void>[]`. So far I've been using `sequenceArray` to map things like this to a `TaskEither<Error, void[]>` but in the current case I'd like to gather the left values, and not the right values.

I tried `swap(sequenceArray(results.map(swap)))` but then I realized that this doesn't even work as I end up with a `void` when there is an error (because left short-circuits). How can I do this mapping correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The complexity comes in from the fact that the `Task` part of the `TaskEither` needs to run before the values can be separated. There is a helper for `Either` in the `Array` section of the library that would be useful here if this were just `Either<Error, void>[]`.

```js
import { separate } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';
const broadcasts: Either<Error, void>[] = broadcastSync(); // Pretend it's not a promise
const errors: Error[] = pipe(
  broadcasts,
  separate,
  ({ left }) => left,
);
```

But now we come back to the `Task` issue. So the question is, what to do with the promise. A simple option is to have an `async` function that resolves all of the `TaskEither`s into `Either`s and then to use the approach above:

```js
import * as A from "fp-ts/lib/Array";
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

declare function broadcasts(): Array<TaskEither<Error, void>>;

async function printErrors() {
  // This fires off all the promises and awaits them.
  const broadcasts = await Promise.all(
    pipe(
      broadcast(),
      A.map((e) => e())
    )
  );

  // Same as above
  console.log(pipe(broadcasts, A.separate, ({ left }) => left));
}
```

The alternative is to write your own separate that returns something like `Task<Separated<A[], B[]>>` that would loop through the `TaskEither`s, fire off the underlying promises, and then collect the results into a new promise that could be awaited.

### Edit

I figured there must be a way to get this working with [`Compactable`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Compactable.ts.html) but I was having trouble deciphering all of the generic types when I made my original post. I've got it working, however, so here is an approach that creates `separate` in a more abstract way:

```js
import * as TE from "fp-ts/lib/TaskEither";
import * as T from "fp-ts/lib/Task";
import * as A from "fp-ts/lib/ReadonlyArray";
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as C from "fp-ts/lib/Compactable";
import { pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

// This is a helper to unflatten the TaskEither
function split<E, A>(either: TE.TaskEither<E, A>): T.Task<E.Either<E, A>> {
  return async () => {
    return await either();
  };
}

// Create something like `A.separate` but for `Task<Either<A,B>[]>`
const separate = C.separate(T.Functor, A.Compactable, A.Functor);

function broadcast(): TE.TaskEither<Error, void>[] {
  return [TE.left(new Error("blah"))];
}

// Here's an example of using `separate` and the other helpers
pipe(
  // Get the TaskEithers
  broadcast(),
  // Natural transform to the type expected by separate
  A.map(split),
  // Task<Either<Error, void>>[] -> Task<Either<Error, void>[]>
  T.sequenceArray,
  // Now we can use separate
  separate,
  // Finally, force the task and use the error values.
  async ({ left }) => {
    console.log(await left());
  },
); // -> [Error]
```

The bit that calls `C.separate` deserves some further explanation. That section of the library defines separation in very abstract terms. In order to get a `separate` function for arbitrary functors, you must pass into it type classes for the wrapper (in this case `Task`), a Compactable instance to inform `separate` how to collect up left values (in this case `A.Compactable`) and a functor for containing the right values (in this case again an array).

Comment: Wow. I'll get back to you once I'm back from my vacation, but I ended up with a simpler solution I just don't have my code here yet.